# Tab Issue with My Tool Kit Data Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, mytoolkit

For showing data in a table format in **UWP** I have used **MyTool Kit** DataGrid in my application. It's working fine,but facing some Issues with **TabStop**. In the grid some of my columns are editable and some of the columns are non editable. I want to provide Tab Stop for editable columns in the grid. I have tried with below property

```
IsTabStop=""False"
```

Still it's not working for this grid. Please help me how can I provide Tab Stop to only editable columns in the My ToolKit DataGrid.

Comment: Did you mean you want to prevent the [Tapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_Tapped) event on one column? `DataGrid` contains header line and items lines, did you want to prevent both headers and items tapped events on one column? Could you please describe the reason why you want to prevent the tap event handle? What behaviors you want to prevent, for example, does the tapped event block the edit action? And please provide some relative code snippet. If I misunderstand you please kindly tell me.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Thanks for your reply. As like I mentioned in my question I am using MyTool Kit datagrid to show data in a table format. I have tried to give tab index for the grid it's showing property but it's not working. Even though I have given tab index it's taking only last index. Please provide your suggestion to solve this issue.